# Is there any way to route get and post to different cluster in MS YARP?

Tags: c#, reverse-proxy, ms-yarp

Do we have any setting option in MS Yarp to send http put/post requests to one cluster and http get to different cluster?

Or any way to apply different header transformation for http put/post and get request?

In this example I am trying to forward the post to createuserapicluster and get to different cluster
getuserapicluster

```
"ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": [
      {
        "RouteId": "user1",
        "ClusterId": "createuserapicluster",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/api/users/{**catch-all}"
        },
        "Transforms": [
          {
            "PathRemovePrefix": "/api/users"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "RouteId": "user2",
        "ClusterId": "getuserapicluster",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/api/users/{**catch-all}"
        },
        "Transforms": [
          {
            "PathRemovePrefix": "/api/users"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Clusters": {
      "createuserapicluster": {
        "Destinations": {
          "destination1": {
            "Address": "https://localhost:8080"
          }
        }
      },
      "getuserapicluster": {
        "Destinations": {
          "Destination1": {
            "Address": "https://localhost:9090/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can match routes based on Method. See https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/config-files.html

"Match": {
"Path": "/something/{**remainder}",
"Methods" : [ "GET", "POST" ],